# Does the client need to install Cuda Toolkit to run the application?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I have finished building my cuda application and would like to install it on the clients PCs.
The cuda toolkit installer is about 2GB. It comes with the compiler, samples, tools, etc.
Is the whole toolkit definitly required to be installed on the client machine?
Is there no lighter version for just the CUDA Runtime API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the whole toolkit definitely required to be installed on the client machine?

No, it isn't.

> Is there no lighter version for just the CUDA Runtime API ?

No, but the EULA allows you to redistribute the library components which your application requires with your application. The simplest solution would be to have your installation/deployment system copy the required toolkit components you built against to a private path which is known to your application or deployment environment. You obviously also need to deploy a supported driver version as well.